# Unable to connect to Internet on PC which is connected via LAN with Router

Tags: desktop

I am able to connect my phone over Wifi which means that my Internet connection is working fine and has no issues with ISP. But my PC is not getting connected to Internet which is connected with my Router via LAN cable. I get a yellow icon on my network connection Icon saying No Internet Access.

Following are the steps which I tried at my end to resolve the issue but that didn’t help:

1. Set the IP address to detect automatically which was by default.
2. Tried to disable IPv6.
3. Tried to disable my Kaspersky AV and tried again
4. Reinstalled Network Adapter
5. Rebooted and also re-configured my Router (TP Link router)

Any other ideas anyone would suggest will be much appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the ipconfig output? Can you ping the default gateway? Can you ping www.google.com? I have seen in some rare cases that even the network icon had the No Internet Access that it was working. Can you check the LAN connection with another computer/cable?

Answer (score 0):

If there is proxy like 10.0.5.21 then you have set your IPv4 properties on use IP address and fill the following detail. then you will be connected easily.

This works if there is no proxy on network.
1st step: Just right click on icon and click on troubleshoot problems.
and click repair.this will fix your IP and all other automatically.

2nd step: Go to status/properties/ then click on IPv6 then click properties set both on address automatically.Then go to IPv4 and do same.